# How to create redux action success & error callback to trigger react component handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i'm creating a register functionality that will show success / fail modal based on the API call response on redux action. I needed a way so that if the axios post in redux action is success, it will allow my register component to trigger it's success handler (method to show success modal within component-level state), and otherwise if the axios post in redux action is fail, it will allow my register component to trigger it's fail handler. I will use component-level state within the register component and passing them as props to separate ModalSuccessRegister and ModalFailRegister components to show and hide them. I don't think it's worth it to have a redux state just to show / hide these modals.

Here's the code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { registerUser } from '../path/to/authActions'
import ModalSuccessRegister from '../path/to/ModalSuccessRegister'
import ModalFailRegister from '../path/to/ModalFailRegister'

const Register = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    showSuccessModal: '',
    showFailModal: ''
  }
  
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  const handler: {
    submitRegister: async () => {
      const userData = {
        username: state.username,
        email: state.email,
        password: state.password
      }
      await props.registerUser(userData)
    },
    closeFailModal: () => {
      setState({ ...state, showFailModal: false })
    },
    closeSuccessModal: () => {
      setState({ ...state, showSuccessModal: false })
    },
  }

  return (
    // just some input fields
    // just some input fields
    <button onClick={handler.submitRegister}></button> 
    
    {state.showSuccessModal ? (
      <ModalSuccessRegister closeModal={handler.closeSuccessModal} />
      ) : null}
    {state.showFailModal ? (
      <ModalFailRegister closeModal={handler.closeFailModal} />
      ) : null}
  )
}

Register.propTypes = {
  registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { registerUser })(Register)
```

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { SET_SUCCESS_REGISTER } from '../path/to/constants'

export const registerUser = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
  await axios.post('/register', userData)
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: SET_SUCCESS_REGISTER,
      payload: true
    }))
    .catch(res => dispatch({
      type: SET_SUCCESS_REGISTER,
      payload: false
    })
}
```

notice that currently the action's registerUser will only dispatch something to reducer when the axios post is success / failed. my intention is to have the .then() and .catch() on the registerUser to trigger some event to the caller component (Register) to define it's own success and error handlers inside the caller component itself (to change the showSuccessModal / showFailModal states accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are updating the state using `SET_SUCCESS_REGISTER` action in reducer so bring in that property in the component and call the modal once it gets updated also you will need a submitted local state so you show modal once form is submitted.

Let's say that property is registerSuccess then you will add this useEffect code.

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if(submitted) {
        if(props.registerSucess) {
          setState({...state, showSuccessModal: true })
        } else {
          setState({...state, showFailModal: true })
        }
      }
    }, [props.registerSuccess])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However it still looks like i need to utilize the registerSuccess state of the redux store. I'd like to have something like if the http request inside the redux action is success / fail, it will send back some kind of event to the caller component so that the caller component (in this case, Register) can define what to do when the action response is either success or fail, so it's not depend on the redux action